# Select quarterly months values

Tags: r, lubridate, data-wrangling, mutate

From the given dataframe i am trying to extract `quarterly_values` however it fails when i try to mutatue every third month values .

```
mont_dates <- c("201401", "201402", "201403", "201404", "201405", 
"201406", "201407", "201408", "201409", "201410", "201411", "201412")
cat <- c("new", "old", "undefined", "new", "old", "undefined", 
"undefined", "new", "old", "undefined", "new", "old")
mont_vals <- c(221, 433, 878, 455, 998, 797, 77, 3435, 868, 686, 868, 434)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
df <- data.frame(mont_dates, mont_vals, cat, ID)
```

Function to extract monthly values and calculate quarterly values

```
 
Monthly_Qrt_vals <- function(df1) {
  df1 %>%
 mutate(mont_dates = ymd(paste0(mont_dates, "01")),
           quarter = paste0(year(mont_dates), " Q", quarter(mont_dates))) %>%
    arrange(mont_dates) %>%
    mutate(quarterly_values = mont_vals[c(1,seq(3, nrow(mont_vals) , by=3)),])
}
result <- df %>% Monthly_Qrt_vals()
View(result)
```

```
         cat ID mont_dates mont_vals quarter
1        new  1 2014-01-01       221 2014 Q1
2        old  2 2014-02-01       433 2014 Q1
3  undefined  3 2014-03-01       878 2014 Q1
4        new  4 2014-04-01       455 2014 Q2
5        old  5 2014-05-01       998 2014 Q2
6  undefined  6 2014-06-01       797 2014 Q2
7  undefined  7 2014-07-01        77 2014 Q3
8        new  8 2014-08-01      3435 2014 Q3
9        old  9 2014-09-01       868 2014 Q3
10 undefined 10 2014-10-01       686 2014 Q4
11       new 11 2014-11-01       868 2014 Q4
12       old 12 2014-12-01       434 2014 Q4
```

**Error**

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `quarterly_values = mont_vals[c(1, seq(3, nrow(mont_vals), by = 3)), ]`.
Caused by error in `seq.default()`:
! 'to' must be of length 1
```

**Expected Outcome**
`quarterly_values` should take values of every third month assign to first row of quarters i.e. `2014 Q1, 2014 Q2`.

The original dataset is of 10 years from `2014-2023` Is there an alternative solution to get `quarterly_values` ?

```
         cat ID mont_dates mont_vals quarter  quarterly_values 
1        new  1 2014-01-01       221 2014 Q1   878
2        old  2 2014-02-01       433 2014 Q1   NA
3  undefined  3 2014-03-01       878 2014 Q1   NA
4        new  4 2014-04-01       455 2014 Q2   797
5        old  5 2014-05-01       998 2014 Q2   NA
6  undefined  6 2014-06-01       797 2014 Q2   NA
7  undefined  7 2014-07-01        77 2014 Q3   77
8        new  8 2014-08-01      3435 2014 Q3   NA
9        old  9 2014-09-01       868 2014 Q3   NA
10 undefined 10 2014-10-01       686 2014 Q4   686
11       new 11 2014-11-01       868 2014 Q4   NA
12       old 12 2014-12-01       434 2014 Q4   NA
```

Comment: Please *do not* add gratuitous mentions of tags to the post title. It’s redundant, and there’s a unanimous consensus against this practice on this site.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry did not know. will bare in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This groups by quarter, then generates `quarterly_values` by setting the first row per quarter equal to the final month's value in that quarter.  It uses `ifelse` to decide whether to fill the row, and `tail` to choose the final value within each group (quarter).

Note the use of `tail` assumes the entries are in date order.  You could sort them first if necessary.

```
df |> 
   mutate(mont_dates = ymd(paste0(mont_dates, "01")),
          quarter = paste0(year(mont_dates), " Q", quarter(mont_dates))) |>
   group_by(quarter) |>
   mutate(quarterly_values=ifelse(row_number()==1 , tail(mont_vals,1) , NA))


# A tibble: 12 × 6
# Groups:   quarter [4]
   mont_dates mont_vals cat          ID quarter quarterly_values
   <date>         <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
 1 2014-01-01       221 new           1 2014 Q1              878
 2 2014-02-01       433 old           2 2014 Q1               NA
 3 2014-03-01       878 undefined     3 2014 Q1               NA
 4 2014-04-01       455 new           4 2014 Q2              797
 5 2014-05-01       998 old           5 2014 Q2               NA
 6 2014-06-01       797 undefined     6 2014 Q2               NA
 7 2014-07-01        77 undefined     7 2014 Q3              868
 8 2014-08-01      3435 new           8 2014 Q3               NA
 9 2014-09-01       868 old           9 2014 Q3               NA
10 2014-10-01       686 undefined    10 2014 Q4              434
11 2014-11-01       868 new          11 2014 Q4               NA
12 2014-12-01       434 old          12 2014 Q4               NA
```

Comment: thanks yes sorry i just realised and have made the correction in expected outcome to reflect the every third month.

Comment: @Sam no problem.  note this solution does assume the dates are in the correct order.  I just noticed the `arrange` in your own code which suggests that you think they might not always be in the correct order to start with.

Comment: thanks, in the original dataframe of 10 years,  i am findings lots of NAs in `mont_vals` how would you deal with that ?

Comment: @Sam it completely depends on what the numbers mean and how an `NA` should be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

A verbose base R approach (which can be written shorter)

```r
within(df[c("cat", "ID", "mont_dates", "mont_vals")], {
  mont_dates = as.Date(paste0(mont_dates, "01"), "%Y%m%d")
  quarter = paste(format(mont_dates, "%Y"), 
                  sprintf("Q%i", (as.POSIXlt(mont_dates)$mon) %/% 3L + 1L))
  quarterly_values = ave(mont_vals, quarter, FUN = \(x) c(x[[3L]], NA, NA))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `quarters` function. For the values we can use `ave`.

```
> within(df, {
+   mont_dates <- as.Date(sprintf('%s01', mont_dates), '%Y%m%d')
+   quarters <- sprintf('%s %s', quarters(mont_dates), strftime(mont_dates, '%Y'))
+   quaterly_values <- ave(mont_vals, quarters, FUN=\(x) replace(rep(NA, 3), 1, x[3]))
+ })
   mont_dates mont_vals       cat ID quaterly_values quarters
1  2014-01-01       221       new  1             878  Q1 2014
2  2014-02-01       433       old  2              NA  Q1 2014
3  2014-03-01       878 undefined  3              NA  Q1 2014
4  2014-04-01       455       new  4             797  Q2 2014
5  2014-05-01       998       old  5              NA  Q2 2014
6  2014-06-01       797 undefined  6              NA  Q2 2014
7  2014-07-01        77 undefined  7             868  Q3 2014
8  2014-08-01      3435       new  8              NA  Q3 2014
9  2014-09-01       868       old  9              NA  Q3 2014
10 2014-10-01       686 undefined 10             434  Q4 2014
11 2014-11-01       868       new 11              NA  Q4 2014
12 2014-12-01       434       old 12              NA  Q4 2014
```

Assuming that the data is complete and in the required order as in the OP.